# Federal Reserve Interest Rate Data has years with differing number of weeks

Tags: date-and-time, finance

I need to compute annual mean interest rates from public data. FRED mortgage rate data (available here: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/MORTGAGE30US) when downloaded as an Excel file, Imports as pairs {date,rate} thus
[image: image of part of data from Fred]

The data available from Fred is 1971 to the present; I am only interested in 1990-2021, inclusive. This code works fine to create a 1670 obs dataset for the 32 year period of interest

```
    intDates = Select[intRates[[All, 1]],DateObject[{1989, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0}] < # <   DateObject[{2022, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}] &]; 
intVals = intRates[[980 ;; 2649]][[All, 2]]; 
intData = Transpose[{intDates, intVals}]; 
intData // Length
```

Problemo: 1670/52 is not an integer. BECAUSE, the Fed produces a value weekly on the same day and some years have 52 readings and some have 53. I would rather not arbitrarily drop data. In my segment of time there are 6 years with 53 readings. One would think, since the code above works fine, this code...

```
    tbl = Transpose[Table[{i, i + 2}, {i, 1989, 2020}]];
reads = MapThread[
   Select[intRates[[All, 1]], 
     DateObject[{#1, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0}] < # < 
      DateObject[{#2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}]] &, tbl];
Length[#]&/@reads
```

...would also, where the strategy is to measure the read count for each year with a year being defined as a period greater than New Year's Eve from the prior year and less than New Year's Day of the following year. But something about DateObject does not cooperate.

I am more than happy to upload my Excel file but have been unable to locate the mechanism for doing so. Once I get past the DateObject problem in MapThread[Select...] I may be over the hump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the data as CSV directly from the website, use `Rest` to drop the first row of the results (i.e. the table headers), and convert the result to a `TimeSeries` object:

```
ts = TimeSeries@Rest@Import["https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/fredgraph.csv?bgcolor=%23e1e9f0&chart_type=line&drp=0&fo=open%20sans&graph_bgcolor=%23ffffff&height=450&mode=fred&recession_bars=on&txtcolor=%23444444&ts=12&tts=12&width=968&nt=0&thu=0&trc=0&show_legend=yes&show_axis_titles=yes&show_tooltip=yes&id=MORTGAGE30US&scale=left&cosd=1971-04-02&coed=2022-06-09&line_color=%234572a7&link_values=false&line_style=solid&mark_type=none&mw=3&lw=2&ost=-99999&oet=99999&mma=0&fml=a&fq=Weekly%2C%20Ending%20Thursday&fam=avg&fgst=lin&fgsnd=2020-02-01&line_index=1&transformation=lin&vintage_date=2022-06-11&revision_date=2022-06-11&nd=1971-04-02","CSV"]
```

Now use `TimeSeriesWindow` in a `Table` to extract subsections of the data, each one calendar year long. To do so, set the window granularity to one year (e.g. using `DateObject[{2021}]` would extract events from the time series that happened in 2021). The table returns a list of value pairs containing the year (as a `DateObject`) and the average for that year. `Mean` will automatically adjust to the number of samples in each subset, whether there are 52 or 53.

```
yearlyAverages = 
  Table[
    {DateObject[{year}], Mean@ TimeSeriesWindow[ts, DateObject[{year}]]}, 
    {year, 1990, 2021}
  ]
```

Finally, use `DateListPlot` to plot the results:

```
DateListPlot[yearlyAverages]
```

[image: date scatterplot of yearly averages]